# How to create a HORIZONTAL white separator line to add to my layout with java?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

i need to create a white separator line with java. I need to add it into my `relativelayout`, but allways with java, because i am learning to use `relativelayout` with java.

I know how to create the line with *xml*:

```
<View
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"/>
```

But now i need to add it into my relative layout with java code:

```
        RelativeLayout rl= new RelativeLayout(this); //Contiene el menu superior con sus botones.

        home= new ImageView(this);
        home.setImageResource(R.drawable.but_home_up);
        rl.addView(home);
        homeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); 
        homeParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
        home.setId(5);
        home.setLayoutParams(homeParams);
```

I want to put the separator line below the *Home* `imageView`.

How can i do it?

I tryed with this code, but it doesn't work... it is painting a VERTICAL LINE, and i want HORIZONTAL:

```
    View line = new View(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lineParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lineParams.setMargins(0,0,10,0);
    lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,5);
    lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lineParams.width=1;
    line.setId(6);
    line.setBackgroundColor(0xFF808080);
    line.setLayoutParams(lineParams);
    rl.addView(line);
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
View v = new View(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewLp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);
viewLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageViewID);
viewLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
viewLp.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

v.setLayoutParams(viewLp);
v.setBackgroundColor(0x808080);

rl.addView(v);
```

Replace in your last code example `lineParams.width = 1;` to `lineParams.height = 1;`. It should work.